# How to animate icon toggle using React.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this component(small, testable) component that toggles an Font Awesome icon.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class IconToggler extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            icon: "fa fa-play fa-5x"
        };
        this.toggleIcon = this.toggleIcon.bind(this);
    }

    toggleIcon(){
        const newIcon = this.state.icon === "fa fa-play fa-5x"? "fa fa-pause fa-5x" : "fa fa-play fa-5x";
        this.setState({icon: newIcon});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <button onClick={this.toggleIcon}><i className={this.state.icon}></i></button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default IconToggler;
```

It's working, but the icons toggle feels rough. How do I make one fade out, and the other fade in?

Comment: https://medium.com/@joethedave/achieving-ui-animations-with-react-the-right-way-562fa8a91935

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

Comment: That should help you understand and create animations.

Comment: Thx a lot, I'm not experienced with animations that don't use jQuery.